# How to check if a string contains any string in a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find if any word of a given string is contained within a column in a mySQL table.

**Example**

String: `'Company LLC'`

Column: `'LLC'`

I've tried the below query but no dice.

```
select * from table
where column sounds like '%Company LLC%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from table
where column rlike replace('Company LLC', ' ', '|')
```

This does a regex match. In regex, the pipe char `|` means "or". The resulting regex means "Company or LLC". In MySQL, rlike matches when any part of the value matches (rather than the whole column matches), so you don't need ".*" on each end.